# Не выполняется плейбук с тэгом в Ansible

Tags: python, ansible

Добрый день. Я добавил теги для обработчиков (stop, start, restart). Выполняю плейбук командой:

```
ansible-playbook playbooks/cassandra_role.yml --tags "restat_cassandra"
```

В итоге плейбук скипает всё таски и не рестартует сервис.

`main.yml` в директории `/handlers` выглядит следующим образом:

```
---
- name: restart cassandra
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  command: systemctl restart cassandra.service
  tags:
     - restart

- name: stop cassandra
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo 
  command: systemctl stop cassandra.service
  tags:
     - stop

- name: start cassandra
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  command: systemctl start cassandra.service
  tags: 
     - start
```

Спасибо за внимание!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы пометили таски тегами: `start`,`stop`,`restart`.

А пытаетесь выполнить `restat_cassandra` – конечно, такого тега нет.

Плюс ко всему, handler'ы сами по себе нельзя исполнить – чтобы сработал обработчик, нужно, чтобы отработала одна из задач, к которой он привязан.

Comment: т.е. лучше написать отдельный таск для этих задач?

PS: restart_cassandra - очепятка, поршу прощения)